# Track time of external Framebuster Form

Tags: javascript, html, popup, external, time-tracking

I wanted to track how long users take to fill in a external Form.

I tried to load the external Form within an Iframe and track the time of the wrapper page using body.onload and body.onunload. 
But the external Form has some Framebuster code to blast of my Iframe.

Do you have any suggestions how to track the time.
I can't access the code of the external Form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like [jQuery Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) and have your form pop out in a modal window? You could then track the initialization and breakdown (close) of said window?

Not sure (without any code posted) how you are doing it now (guessing a simple popup? or in page iframe?)

Comment: Yes so far i tried a popup and an Iframe.
I try to frame this url: http://ec.europa.eu/yourvoice/ipm/forms/dispatch?form=tobacco6

Colorbox get also Framebusted.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to see if the form submission logic on the server is session-protected, so you may have a chance to display a local copy, and submit it to the original processing script at the external server?